# error on uploading to digitalocean spaces using shrine and aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-sdk, digital-ocean, shrine

I am using shrine to directly upload to `aws-s3` bucket and is working fine. Now I want to use DigitalOcean `spaces` instead. So I changed some settings for shrine like below(only changed the `env` variables relevant to spaces).

```
require "shrine"
require "shrine/storage/s3"

s3_options = {
    access_key_id: ENV["SPACES_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    secret_access_key: ENV["SPACES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
    region: ENV["SPACES_REGION"],
    bucket: ENV["SPACES_BUCKET"],
    endpoint: ENV["SPACES_ENDPOINT"]
}

Shrine.storages = {
    cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache", upload_options: {acl: "public-read"}, **s3_options),
    store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store", upload_options: {acl: "public-read"}, **s3_options),
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :presign_endpoint
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
Shrine.plugin :backgrounding

Shrine::Attacher.promote {|data| UploadJob.perform_async(data)}
Shrine::Attacher.delete {|data| DeleteJob.perform_async(data)}
```

I also added cors in spaces to allow all requests like below

[image: Cors settings]

But when I upload I am getting this error.

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Policy missing condition: Content-Type</Message><BucketName>testing-dev</BucketName><RequestId>tx0000000036366363370-3663t37373-33883-sgp1a</RequestId><HostId>349494-sgp1a-sgp</HostId></Error>
```

What could be the issue here? I can see that the error telling `content-type` missing in policy. But how can I add that if thats the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that DigitalOcean Spaces now requires the presign policy to include `contentType` condition. The presign policy is generated in the presign endpoint, so you can tell it to add `:content_type` based on the `filename` query parameter:

```
Shrine.plugin :presign_endpoint, presign_options: -> (request) do
  filename     = request.params["filename"]
  extension    = File.extname(filename)
  content_type = Rack::Mime.mime_type(extension)

  { content_type: content_type }
end
```

This should make `:content_type` always present, because if the `filename` has no extension or the extension is unrecognised, `Rack::Mime.mime_type` will return `application/octet-stream`, which is the content type S3 assigns to objects by default anyway.

Just make sure you're passing the `filename` query parameter on the client side when sending the presign request. E.g. using `window.fetch` it would be:

```
fetch('/presign?filename=' + file.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is to add `contentType` manually.

So I updated like this

```
Shrine.storages = {
    cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache", upload_options: {acl: "public-read", content_type: "png/jpeg"}, **s3_options),
    store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store", upload_options: {acl: "public-read", content_type: "png/jpeg"}, **s3_options),
}
```

I dont know this is the best approach as per shrine docs it will set `contentType` automatically based on `mime type` and will work fine when uploading to amazon `s3`. But somehow this is not working with `digitalocean`. So we have to manually specify like this to make this working with spaces.

Comment: This works because the options from `:upload_options` are also passed in when generating the presign. However, as you said, this would make the content type hardcoded and not actually reflect the MIME type of the uploaded file. I provided an alternative solution.

Comment: @janko-m Thank you for making this clear. Such a great gem. :)